# Bridging from Objective C to Swift with PromiseKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, promisekit

Using PromiseKit 2.0 with Swift 1.2, I'm trying to use a PMKPromise that was created in Objective C from Swift.

Objective C code:

```
@interface FooTest : NSObject
+ (PMKPromise *)promise;
@end
```

Swift code (I've tried a number of variations, none of which work. This one is closest to the example given at http://promisekit.org/PromiseKit-2.0-Released/):

```
FooTest.promise().then { (obj: AnyObject?) in
    self.obj = obj
}
```

Compiler error: Cannot invoke 'then' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject?) -> _)'

This doesn't work either:

```
FooTest.promise().then { (obj: AnyObject?) -> AnyPromise in
    return AnyPromise()
}
```

Similar error: "Cannot invoke 'then' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject?) -> AnyPromise)'"

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Sources/AnyPromise.h

Comment: Um, well okay but I'm pretty sure it's not as simple as knowing just the declaration, as there are #defines and other bridging magic going on. `- (AnyPromise *(^)(id))then;`

Comment: Well, I let you down. :( Sorry.

Comment: did you create a bridging header?

Comment: @Steve yes there's a bridging header

Comment: From what I can tell it doesn't seem PromiseKit is ready for Swift (this is an opinion, I realize, and before the gauntlets are released hear me out). The `then` call still uses `id` to allow multiple types of blocks to be passed in; in swift this probably should be done by overloading `then` and using the proper type signatures. I will try to look into a solution for a little bit, but this appears to be pretty mucky to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different promise classes in PromiseKit, one for Swift (`Promise<T>`) and one for ObjC (`AnyPromise`). The Swift ones are generic and Objective-C cannot see generic classes, so this is why there are two.

If `Foo.promise()` is meant to be used in both ObjC and Swift then you are doing the right thing. If however you only intend to use this promise in Swift then I suggest rewriting it as a `Promise<T>`.

To use an Objective-C `AnyPromise` (`PMKPromise` is a deprecated alias for `AnyPromise`: prefer `AnyPromise`) in Swift code you must splice it into a an existing chain.

```
someSwiftPromise().then { _ -> AnyPromise in
    return someAnyPromise()
}.then { (obj: AnyObject?) -> Void in
    //…
}
```

There *should* be a way to start from an AnyPromise, probably I will add this later today:

```
someAnyPromise().then { (obj: AnyObject?) -> Void in
    //…
}
```

Expect a 2.1 update. [edit: 2.1 pushed with the above `then` added]